# Confusing Function in C++ Dialogs

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, graphics

Hi could anyone explain to me what this function is doing, I am currently reading a programming book and am struggling to follow this function.

From what I can gather the function take in a handle to a window (in this case a dialog box), then information is passed in the second param and the third param being a pointer to the actual object.

To give some context I'm trying to populate a combo box with the adapters that a computer has.

```
void AddItem(HWND hWnd, char *ch, void *pData) 
{
  WPARAM nI = (WPARAM)((int)(DWORD)SendMessage(hWnd,CB_ADDSTRING,0,(LPARAM)ch));

  SendMessage(hWnd,CB_SETITEMDATA, nI, (LPARAM)pData);
}
```

here is an example call:

```
for (UINT a=0; a<m_dwNumAdapters; a++) 
{
   AddItem(m_hADAPTER, m_xAdapterInfo[a].d3dAdapterIdentifier.Description,
           &m_xAdapterInfo[a]);
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used earlier something like this to add items to combo box,  I might be of help.

```
SendDlgItemMessage(hwnd, IDC_COMBOSTATUS, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM) (LPCTSTR) "Available");
```

Where hwnd is handle to dialog, IDC_COMBOSTATUS is resource ID, and other is pretty much clear.

Try SendDlgItemMessage function rather SendMessage.

Regards,

Vajda

Comment: That would probably be more useful than what I am currently using, I'll give it a go.

Comment: That doesn't do quite the same as Herly's function which also sends a `CB_SETITEMDATA` message.

Comment: @David Yes, you're right, but I just wrote that part which replaces his SendMessage function, all the other should be the same.

Answer (score 1):

It adds a string value and associated integer to a combo box.

The aspect you may be missing is that list boxes, combos etc. store an integer value (the same size as a pointer) in a list parallel to the list of text labels.  You can put whatever you like in the integer value.  For example you could put in a pointer to some `struct` containing further information.

When you need to respond to the user's selection, you simply read out the selected integer value, cast it to a pointer, and do something with that information.

Of course, many lists and combos don't need any of this (a simple string suffices) and so `0` would typically be passed.

Comment: Thanks that helped explain what one of the parameters is doing, wondered why it was being passed a position in an array, makes better sense now.